# How get push notification in real time with Framework7 Cordova

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

I'm using framework 7 to develop an Android Hybrid Mobile Application and I almost did except push notification. Now, I don't know how to add push notification in framework7.

Earlier, I developed a lot of PhoneGap Applications and I often use PhoneGap plugin add phonegap-plugin-push and this work like a charm for me.

But my bad luck it is not working with framework7. (http://framework7.io/)

Please guide me to add real-time notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem by using Cordova-push-plugin.
here is the code.

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    modalTitle: "VDST",
    // Enable Material theme
    material: true,

});
 myApp.push = PushNotification.init({
     "android": {
        "senderID": "xxxxxxxxxx"
       },  "ios": {
       "sound": true,
        "vibration": true,
        "badge": true
         },
        "windows": {}
        });

    myApp.push.on('registration', function(data) {
       var oldRegId = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
         if (oldRegId !== data.registrationId) {
           localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId);
           var token=data.registrationId;
           myApp.alert(token);
            }
           });
        myApp.push.on('error', function(e) {
               console.log("push error = " + e.message);
             });
        myApp.push.on('notification', function(data) {
             console.log('notification event');
             var cards = document.getElementById("cards");
             var push = '<div class="row">' +
                       '<div class="col s12 m6">' +
                        '<div class="card darken-1">' +
                        '<div class="card-content black-text">' +
                    '<span class="card-title black-text">' + data.title + '</span>' +
                    '      <p>' + data.message + '</p>' +
                   '      <p>' + data.additionalData.foreground + '</p>' +
                           '    </div>' +
                            '  </div>' +
                           ' </div>' +
                          '</div>';
                        cards.innerHTML += push;
                    });
```

Here is full reference:

http://macdonst.github.io/push-workshop/index.html